# IS IT permissible to use money won from gambling

Tags: halal-haram, money, gambling

Assalamualaikum is it haram to use money won from gambling

Comment: Is the money earned by gambling halal?

Answer (score 1):

No.

Gambling is forbidden in Islam, therefore the money is as well.

Answer (score 0):

Money won from gambiling is haram money and its not permissiable to use it